# how can you import a live website to an old replica of that same website hosted locally on MAMP

Tags: wordpress

so basically the website it’s already live and I’ve been editing stuff on the live website so now the replica on my local host it’s outdated and it doesn’t have the same pages or the same plug-ins installed. My question is how can I import everything and make my local host website an exact replica of the live one?

I downloaded the whole /wp_content folder and exported SQL from live into my MAMP site but it didn't add the new pages and the menu still looks like the old one instead of the live one

Answer (score 0):

Try pulling all the whole wp files and compress it. Then create a new folder with a name and extract it there, then change the database settings in the wp-config.php file to the localhost details.